# SSH logins to two AWS servers, one working one not

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I know there are many questions and answers on this topic, but I'm still foxed.

I have a server on AWS running for a long time and the ssh has always worked, using a .pem file and no password.

Now I have a second similar server running under the same security group: but I cannot ssh into it from the same client computer. **However I can ssh both old and new servers from the Android app Juice**, using of course the same .pem file to identify myself.

What else could be going on? I have checked the permissions of the .pem file (400)

I have done detailed logs of each one, working and failing.

Things start to deviate about here: this is the working one:

```
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mike/.ssh/mms-aws.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: DSA SHA256:6YSh etc
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (
```

And this is the failing one:

```
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/mike/.ssh/mms-aws.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: DSA SHA256:6YSh etc
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any and all help and suggestions welcome. Local computer is Ubuntu 16.04. Old EC2 instance is Ubuntu 12. New server is Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using a new key-pair created for the new instance (but the same security group), I've been able to log in as ubuntu@... and sudo and set up a user and ssh as that user. SOLVED.

Maybe the version of openssh detected that the key-pair was used in two places and didn't like that.

Still odd that it worked from Juice though.